# How to get data from ASP Form?

Tags: asp.net, forms, textbox, return-value, change-password

I want to call ID from current password and new password.
how can i call them in asp.net?
because it's not same like html.
can somebody share to me?

```
<p>
<asp:Label ID="CurrentPasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="CurrentPassword">Old Password:</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="CurrentPassword" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="CurrentPasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="CurrentPassword" CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Old Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</p>
```

How can i call **currentpassword** id?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you need the ID?

Comment: public void ChangePass(HttpSessionState Session, string OldPassword, string NewUPassword)